# PGFPLOTS incomplete grid, missing minor grid both right and up directions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

[image]I am making a file with `pgfplot` package and I want the grid to be with minor grids line complete from both sides, this is my trial:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\usetikzlibrary
{
    intersections, decorations.markings, angles,
    quotes, calc, arrows, arrows.meta,shapes.geometric
}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemformula}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{fig2.tikz}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            
            
            \pgfplotsset{
                tick label style = {font = {\fontsize{11.25}{14}\selectfont}},
                label style = {font = {\fontsize{11.25}{14}\selectfont}},
                legend style = {font = {\fontsize{11.25}{14}\selectfont}},
            }
            
            
            \pgfplotsset{
                outer axis line style={thick,},
                grid = both,
                tickwidth = 0.25cm,
                set layers,
            }
            
            
            
            \begin{axis}[anchor=origin,
            grid=both,
                grid style={thin, draw=gray!20},
                major grid style={thin,draw=gray!50},
                minor x tick num={3},
                minor y tick num={4},
                minor tick length=0pt,
                xmin=-4,xmax=4,
                ymin=-16,ymax=4,
                xlabel={$x$},
                xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=west},
                ylabel={$y$},
                ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south},
                xtick={-3,...,3},
                tickwidth=0.25cm,
                major tick style={black,thick},
                extra x ticks={-4,0,4},
                extra x tick labels={,0,},
                extra x tick style={grid=both,black,
                    major tick style={draw=none},
                    tick label style={anchor=north east,xshift=-.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}},},
                ytick={-14,-12,...,2},
                extra y ticks={-16, 4},
                extra y tick style={grid=both,major tick style={draw=none},},
                extra y tick labels={},
                axis lines=middle,
                scale only axis,
                axis line style={>={Stealth[scale=1.2]},<->,thick},
                samples=1000]
                
                \addplot[domain=-4:4,draw=red,draw opacity=0.1,fill=red,fill opacity=0.1] {(3*x-2)*(x+3)}--(4,4)--(4,-16)--(-4,-16)--(-4,4)--cycle;
                \addplot[domain=-4:4,draw=red,dashed] {(3*x-2)*(x+3)};
                
            
            \end{axis}  
            
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{filecontents}
    
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apart from your code being overly complicated creating a file for the plot and the re-adding the image to the document, it seems to be working just fine and I see minor grids for both axes. Can you maybe add an image of your output and indicate what is missing?

Comment: Dear Mr Markus, I added an image which declares both sides that are missing the minor grids, thanks you for your reply, also would you please tell me if there is an easier way to write this function with the same styles I used as these are my vendors requests. I would appreciate very much your help.

Comment: Why my question was closed, I didn't get any answers yet and the mentioned question didn't answer mine.